# Kinematics - distance traveled with varying acceleration

Tags: kinematics

A point particle starts from rest and accelerates forward at $2\frac{m}{s^2}$ for 4 seconds. Then decelerates at a rate of $4\frac{m}{s^2}$ for an additional 2 seconds. How far has the particle traveled over the 6 seconds?

Answer (score 1):

You can do this in multiple ways, with different approachs. You can use calculus, or graphs, or the traditional equations of 1-dimensional movements.

Assuming you don't know Calculus, we will do it by graph ways:

Assuming that in $t=0$ we had that $v_o=0$, accelerating $2m/s^2$ during 4 seconds, we'll have:
$$ v = v_o + at$$
$ v = 8m/s $
. And then desaccelerates $4m/s^2$ in 2 seconds, so (by the same formula)
$v_f = 0$

Notice that in a graph, the velocity in therms of t will form a triangle, and the area under this triangle will be the total distance the particle has travelled.
We will calculate the area by dividing it in two triangles (one with 4 base and 8 height, and the other with 2 base and 8 height).
The total area will be
$$ A = A_1 + A_2 $$
So
$$A_1 = \frac{4•8}{2} = 16 $$
And
$$ A_1 = \frac{2•8}{2} = 8 $$
So the area (and distance) is 24m.

I should warn you OP: always post what you have tried. It is really important.